# Access to Star Alliance Gold lounges at Singapore with children

Tags: children, lounges, singapore-airlines, star-alliance, sin

I will soon be traveling through Singapore Changi Airport with family.  As a Singapore Airlines Krisflyer Gold member, I'm entitled to bring one (1) guest traveling on Star Alliance flights to any Star Alliance Gold (*G) lounge.

However, individual airline policies for children vary widely, with some like Air New Zealand permitting all children under 12 free of change and others like Singapore Airlines counting all children as additional guests -- although apparently enforcement of this varies.

**Are there any *G lounges at SIN that we can enter as a family?**  I'm willing to pay a reasonable amount for the kids if needed, in cash or miles, but options like Plaza Premium where we all need to pay ($58/person!) are not reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singapore Changi has only [three Star Alliance lounges](https://www.staralliance.com/en/airport-details?airportCode=SIN): the Singapore Airlines KrisFlyer Gold lounges in T2 and T3, and a Royal Silk Thai Airways lounge in T1.  (There are a couple of contract lounges as well, but these are only accessible if you're flying their contracted airlines like United or Air China.)  All appear to *officially* apply the [Star Alliance lounge policy](https://www.staralliance.com/en/lounge-access-policy), which allows only one (1) guest, excepting only children under two.

However, in *practice*, anecdotal evidence says that Singapore Airlines *does* allow children to enter with their families.  This proved to be the case for us as well: we were told the official policy, but let in as a "one-time exception" before I even had the chance to ask.  It likely helped that the lounge was fairly quiet at the time.