# Krisflyer Gold Lounge extra guest access

Tags: air-travel, lounges, singapore-airlines, sin

Travelling through Changi on Singapore Airlines on a partners gold elite card we have a third person with us we would like to take into the Krisflyer Gold Lounge. Can we pay for his access?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Could you [edit], please, to clarify what you mean by "partners gold elite card"? Are you referring to the Air New Zealand program? Singapore has dozens of partners with "gold elite" membership tiers.

Comment: Or do you mean ”partner’s”

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there is no paid access for Krisflyer Gold lounges.

See also: [Access to Star Alliance Gold lounges at Singapore with children](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139394/access-to-star-alliance-gold-lounges-at-singapore-with-children)